# How to keep minibuffer height compact as possible?

Tags: minibuffer

I am using `GNU Emacs 26.3` under `iTerm2`. My goal is to keep minibuffer size as compact/minimum as possible.

Default height view:

[image]

---

Sometimes minibuffer's height increases and remains as it is. The empty space is small but I cat detected it, since I spent hours in `emacs`.

- I observe that when the `iTerm2`'s size is changed (increased and decreased) it also affects the minibuffer's size.
- When I restarted the `emacs` minibuffer size may still remain with the additional empty space. I am not sure this is result of `iTerm` or `emacs`'s configuration.

---

Example of increased minibuffer height:

[image]

Comment: When you encounter the second case, try doing `M-x top-level RET` and see if the minibuffer starts behaving as you exprect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program running inside of a terminal only knows how many whole lines of text will fit. Most terminals just leave the extra space empty, filled with just the background color. Resize the window slowly and watch what happens as the lower edge of the window approaches the bottom of the visible text in the window.

Emacs has a GUI as well, which allows it much more flexibility than it has when it runs inside a terminal. You might prefer it.

Comment: I get used to using emacs inside terminal where switch between panels to run linux commands and get back to emacs again. I think I cannot function in Emacs GUI

Comment: I observe the same behavior with the Emacs GUI as well

Comment: You might look into using `M-x eshell` or `M-x shell` inside of Emacs :) As for the other issue, on Linux at least the GUI limits it's own window height so that it always has room for a whole number of lines of text. On other platforms it may do something else.

Comment: Ah `eshell` is way different world for me :) Sometimes it does not detect the python-venv environment or my aliases